# Does XML deserialize lock the file from reading?

Tags: c#

I have an xml file which is used by multiple process for reading. Here is the code snippet used for deserializing the xml. I want to make sure the below code does not read lock the file.

```
public Address TestReadLock(string myXmlFile)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myXmlFile))
    {
        XmlReaderSettings xrs = new XmlReaderSettings();
        xrs.ValidationType = ValidationType.None;
        xrs.XmlResolver = null;
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sr, xrs))
        {
            return (Address)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried testing this by creating a dll of above function and loaded the file through powershell and VS in a loop at same time it  worked fine.

```
public void Main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        Address myaddress = TestReadLock(@C:\MyDetails.xml")
    }
}
```

Based on my understanding the above code should read lock the file nad while testing it is not the case

Is there a possibility like testing I did is wrong or my understanding is not correct?

Comment: You've created a non-parallel loop, so that multithreading does not apply to your test. You might want to go for [`Parallel.For`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for.aspx) to test a multithreaded scenario.

Comment: Try using File.ReadAllBytes method and create the stream from bytes readed from the file. Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx link, it will close the file after reading. Note that this approach is not suitable for writing the file

Comment: Thanks for the reply. file is used by multiple process which has same kind of code for reading.not threads .

Comment: Locking file depends on `Stream` `FileShare` constructor argument, not on what you are doing with stream.

Comment: @thanu and what should be the difference in this scenario? you have a multi-threaded/multi-process scenario, so your test is simply not taking that into account.

Comment: @Andreas: Yes but I am wondering why my test is not read locking the file. I am loading this through powershell and VS at same time around 1000 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new StreamReader(string)` uses `FileAccess.Read` and `FileShare.Read` - it will not prevent other readers. If you want different control: use `FileStream` directly to control the access / sharing.

Comment: Thanks Marc this answers my question on why the file is not locking while reading. All of the process will read only the file and as it is not locking other process from reading I will continue using the same code